# Change event from bootstrap-datepicker not picked up by Stimulus js

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, stimulusjs

Is it possible to trigger [stimulus js](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions) from [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)?
(I'm using it via [bootstrap-datepicker-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails))

In my old jQuery code the [changeDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html?highlight=changeDate#changedate) event is triggered no problem:

```js
$(document).on('changeDate', '#my_form .datepicker', function(e) {
```

The `change` event also gets triggered in jQuery (added [here](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1832)?)
So changing `changeDate` to `change` above works the same.

But the `change` event is not being triggered in Stimulus, EG on my datepicker text field:

```rb
data: { action: 'change->next-date#submit' }
```

isn't triggering the submit method in the controller. The `input` event will trigger if you enter text, but this is not the event triggered by the datepicker.
Should the `change` event not work here for Stimulus?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this in the stimulus controller's `connect()` method works to trigger the `change` event:

```js
$(this.datepickerTarget).datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {
  const event = new Event('change')
  this.dispatchEvent(event)
})
```

This enables a data-action attribute hook into a stimulus method:

```rb
          <%= text_field_tag :next_date, params[:next_date],
            data: { action: 'change->next-date#submit',
                    'next-date-target': 'datepicker'
            }
          %>
```

to hook into a stimulus method